# Python psychopy imageStim

Tags: python, psychopy

I'm using psychopy to get an image on a window like this:

```
from psychopy import visual
window = visual.Window(size= (1000,600), units = 'pix', pos = (10,10))
stimulusimage = ('C:\Users\name\Documents\Python Scripts\Project\stimuli\Visual Stimuli\Positive\1.jpg')
showingimage = visual.ImageStim(window, image=stimulusimage)
window.flip()
```

I don't see an image on the window and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I don't get any error message.

Comment: You should probably avoid full absolute paths, and use relative ones instead (i.e. relative to where your PsychoPy script is located). Also, backslashes are escape characters for Python and can cause unexpected results, so you should use forward slashes instead (still work on Windows): `stimulusimage = 'stimuli/Visual Stimuli/Positive/1.jpg'`

Comment: For basic usage like this, there are a bunch of demo scripts that are intended to be helpful examples or working code. See the Coder > Demo menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to draw the image before you flip the window:

```
showingimage.draw()
window.flip()
```

Otherwise it will show a blank screen. By the way, you need not put the filename in parentheses.